# Slow processing of function in C# on different machines

Tags: c#

I am working on windows desktop application. It is being used by many users in production. problem I am facing is that some of the users are reporting slow processing of one of the functionality. However on some other users, it is working fast enough. When i have gone through logs, I found that one function is taking too much time. This function is basically reading records of HTMLTable throgh screen scrapping. Where it is working fast, it is taking around 4-5 seconds. But where it is working slow, it is taking around 40+ seconds. I am not sure what is causing this.

Can you please help on this.

```
private DataTable ReadGridRecords(HTMLTable htmlTable)
{
    this.LogFunctionStart();
    DataTable tasktable = new DataTable();
    header = true;
    int nullrowcount = 0;
    Dictionary<string, int> HeaderCells = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    try
    {
        foreach (HTMLTableRow tr in htmlTable.rows)
        {
            nullrowcount++;
            if (header)
            {
                header = false;
                IHTMLElementCollection thEleColl = tr.getElementsByTagName("th");
                if (thEleColl.length > 0)
                {
                    //this.LogMessage("Shah:Inside ReadGridRecords method starting reading grid headers table" + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ".Stopwatch elapsed: " + stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString());
                    foreach (HTMLTableCell td in thEleColl)
                    {
                        if (td != null && td.innerText != null)
                        {
                            if (td.innerText.ToString().ToUpper().Equals("CREATE_TS"))
                                tasktable.Columns.Add(td.innerText.ToString().ToUpper(), typeof(DateTime));
                            else
                                tasktable.Columns.Add(td.innerText.ToString().ToUpper());
                            HeaderCells.Add(td.innerText.ToString(), td.cellIndex);
                        }
                    }
                }
                //this.LogMessage("Shah:Inside ReadGridRecords method end reading grid headers table" + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ".Stopwatch elapsed: " + stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                dr1 = tasktable.NewRow();
                if (nullrowcount >= 3)
                {
                    //this.LogMessage("Shah:Inside ReadGridRecords method start reading grid rows table Row number:" + nullrowcount.ToString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ".Stopwatch elapsed: " + stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString());
                    IHTMLElementCollection tdEleColl = tr.getElementsByTagName("td");
                    if (tdEleColl.length > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (HTMLTableCell td in tdEleColl)
                        {
                            try
                            {

                                if (td != null && HeaderCells.ContainsValue(td.cellIndex))
                                {
                                    var Key = HeaderCells.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.Equals(td.cellIndex)).Key;
                                    if (td.innerText != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(td.innerText.ToString().Trim()))
                                    {
                                        if (Key.Equals("CREATE_TS"))
                                            dr1[Key] = Convert.ToDateTime(td.innerText.ToString());
                                        else
                                            dr1[Key] = td.innerText.ToString();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (Key.Equals("CREATE_TS"))
                                            dr1[Key] = DateTime.MinValue;
                                        else
                                            dr1[Key] = string.Empty;
                                    }


                                }
                                else if (td != null && td.innerHTML != null && td.innerText != null && td.innerText.ToString().Trim().ToLower().Equals("No record found".ToLower()))
                                {
                                    return tasktable;
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                this.LogMessage(ex.StackTrace.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                        //this.LogMessage("Shah:Inside ReadGridRecords method end reading grid rows table Row number:" + nullrowcount.ToString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ".Stopwatch elapsed: " + stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString());
                        tasktable.Rows.Add(dr1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.LogException(ex);
        this.LogMessage(ex.StackTrace.ToString());
    }
    this.LogFunctionEnd();
    return tasktable;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the different servers get different sized html tables?

Comment: Is the time it takes to load the page (contact the server that is hosting the page with the table) included in the 40 sek? Might there be different network response times for different servers?

Comment: My function starts only when that grid or html table is loaded properly.. and i am seeing this different timing for function executions.

Comment: what else can be done to identify the root cause.

Comment: I see there is error logging on exceptions. Do you see any errors logged? I can't see any other "external" dependency except logging (by external I mean code that calls outside your method)

Comment: Of course the component that you are using to parse html might also be the issue. Many people seem to use https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack to parse html

Comment: Also the dictionary HeaderCells has the wrong key. It is used to look up the name by its index. It should be declared `Dictionary<int, string>` *not* `Dictionary<string, int>`. Then you can write var `Key =  HeaderCells[td.cellIndex]` instead of var `Key = HeaderCells.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.Equals(td.cellIndex)).Key;` which can be much slower